Problems with Running the Compilation Process
Description:
When executing the npm run dev command, Laravel throws the following error:

ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js 6:11-43 Module not found: Error: Can't
resolve './Pages' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\inertia-pos\resources\js'
webpack compiled with 1 error

Additional Information

InertiaJS version: 0.11.0

Inertia-vue3 version: 0.6.0

Vue version: 3.2.29


I'm new to this and I'm building a Laravel-based web cashier app. I'm stuck on this error. Any tips on how to fix it?
